# Blender how to round edges of face

Tags: blender, blender-2.61, blender-2.50, blender-2.67, blender-2.49

I'm trying to make a round eye in my object by selecting a face, pressing e, dragging it into the face a little bit and I'm trying to make that eye round instead of square. How can I do this?

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

Comment: yeah you should ask in http://blender.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Here's another pretty good alternative: Belvel Modifier.
Given at [Blender StackExchange](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2534/how-can-i-round-the-edges-of-a-mesh)

Answer (score 7):

There is "To Sphere" <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> available under Mesh->Transform. As the name suggests it adds a spherical influence, if the selected verts lay flat on a plane the result is circular.

Another option is an addon called LoopTools. Enable it and you have some extra options in the specials menu (<kbd>W</kbd>) which includes Circle, which will give a circular influence to the selected vertices.

Comment: Very nice! I just used your "To Sphere" tip on 2.79 to round out a cone.